# WPF - ItemsSource equivalent for Table in FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemssource

I'm trying to create a `Table` inside a `FlowDocument` inside a `FlowDocumentPageViewer`, as seen in [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/kashyapa/archive/2010/01/11/html-like-table-creation-in-wpf.aspx).  I've never created a table in WPF before, and I was expecting there to be an `ItemsSource`property to which I could bind, like with a `ListBox`.  I want to customize the template for each row, and I want each row's source to be an item in a collection that I pass to the entire table.  So I'll have a `List<MyClass>` instance that would be passed to the table, and each row would show a single `MyClass`.  How can I do that?  Do I not want to use a `Table` within a `FlowDocument`?  The reason I wanted to use some kind of tabular format is so that I can have a single row of column names that applies to all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I wanted was to use `ListView`, thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1):

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" MinWidth="400"
    MinHeight="200">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MyFirstField}"
                    Header="First Field"/>
                <GridViewColumn
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MySecondField}"
                    Header="Second Field"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```